# Why $\sum_{k\leq n}\sum_{d\mid k}=\sum_{d\leq n}\sum_{k\leq \lfloor n/d\rfloor }$?

Tags: number-theory

In a number theory exercise, they use the formula $$\sum_{k\leq n}\sum_{d\mid k}=\sum_{d\leq n}\sum_{k\leq \lfloor n/d\rfloor },$$
but I really don't understand why it's true.

We sum on $$\{(k,d)\mid k\in \{1,...,n\}, \exists s: ds=k \}.$$
So if we fixe a divisor $d$ of $k$, why $k\in \{1,2,...,\frac{n}{d}\}$ ? There is something I really don't get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k\le n}\sum_{d\mid k}a_{k,d}$$
is the sum of $a_{k,d}$ where $k$ and $d$ vary through
all pairs of numbers between $1$ and $n$ inclusive with $k$ a multiple
of $d$. For a $d$ between $1$ and $n$ the $a_{k,d}$ that occur
in this sum are $a_{d,d},a_{2d,d},\ldots,a_{rd,d}$ where $r=\lfloor n/d\rfloor$. Therefore
$$\sum_{k\le n}\sum_{d\mid k}a_{k,d}=\sum_{d\le n}\sum_{j\le\lfloor n/d\rfloor}
a_{jd,d}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a change of variable: if $d \mid k \le n$, then write $k=sd$ and so $s \le \lfloor n/d \rfloor$.